# How to remove extra stuff at front and end of html fetched via xpath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I met a problem recently playing around with Scrapy .

consider the situation:

A json array that placed in a textarea wrapper

```
<div id="example">
  <textarea>
                            [{"type":"\u8d4f\u82b1","sub":[{"sname":"\u5a7a\u6e90","sid":"440a8cc57454b0656bc5b1f1","surl":"wuyuan"},{"sname":"\u7f57\u5e73","sid":"ded1be78733fb2cc70c021f4","surl":"luoping"},{"sname":"\u6d1b\u9633","sid":"f77d6111526fb820db6efaf3","surl":"luoyang"},{"sname":"\u5174\u5316","sid":"700cac1d394cbc1a34e154c3","surl":"xinghua"},{"sname":"\u4eac\u90fd","sid":"bf34d1b18b0036d9222ef5d9","surl":"jingdu"}]},{"type":"\u8d2d\u7269","sub":[{"sname":"\u8fea\u62dc","sid":"b710d6f3c821e59aba1c29d5","surl":"dibai"},{"sname":"\u6cf0\u56fd","sid":"e524735691f256c0a53e8ffb","surl":"taiguo"},{"sname":"\u97e9\u56fd","sid":"d7e376b3690f23d1dc24bbfb","surl":"hanguo"},{"sname":"\u9999\u6e2f","sid":"d7e376b3690f23d1dc24bbfb","surl":"xianggang"},{"sname":"\u65b0\u52a0\u5761","sid":"b15d7068c2f160adbc2c83fb","surl":"xinjiapo"}]},{"type":"\u8e0f\u9752","sub":[{"sname":"\u9ec4\u5c71","sid":"6701f1153f0fd41f975775f3","surl":"huangshan"},{"sname":"\u91ce\u4e09\u5761","sid":"da679613cd1729d6be7822fd","surl":"yesanpo"},{"sname":"\u4e39\u971e\u5c71","sid":"b6ca381b2120f8ccda001fdd","surl":"danxiashan"},{"sname":"\u5341\u6e21","sid":"36eb66d6c4365b0af2c94bfe","surl":"shidu"},{"sname":"\u5e90\u5c71","sid":"9a06d41f975780992b0773fa","surl":"lushan"}]},{"type":"\u6444\u5f71","sub":[{"sname":"\u5357\u4eac","sid":"1e7451eeeb69e222608ca2f4","surl":"nanjing"},{"sname":"\u745e\u58eb","sid":"ad2cb39f09736a7351eea7fb","surl":"ruishi"},{"sname":"\u676d\u5dde","sid":"440a8cc57454b0656bc5b1f1","surl":"hangzhou"},{"sname":"\u4e91\u5357","sid":"17070a5c91ca872746461bf4","surl":"yunnan"},{"sname":"\u5e03\u62c9\u683c","sid":"1e7b51eeeb69e222608ca2fb","surl":"bulage"}]}]

  </textarea>
</div>
```

using `xpath('//*[@id="example"]/textarea/text()')` i can fetch the json array, but there is a problem ,see the pic below:

the `xpath` is different because one is for example and the other one is from my dev.so its not a big deal

[image]

as you can see , at the beginning and ending, there are extra `[u'\r\n`      and `\r\n  ]`

i want to convert it to json so that i can iterate the json array,i use json.loads(),but an error occurs and says

```
>>> json.loads(response.xpath('//*[@id="J-head-menu"]/li[1]/textarea/text()').extract())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

If i remove the extra stuff manually,it will be working,so,here is what i think,i should remove the extra stuff around the json,but i tried many way but failed,the type `response.xpath()` returns is not string but a list,so how to address it? i have no ideas,anyone does? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="example"]/textarea/text()').extract()[0].strip()
```

solves this problem !!

Answer (score 1):

In xpath `normalize-space` should help removing unwanted leading and trailing whitespace. `xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="example"]/textarea/text())')` should work.

However, this will also replace sequences of whitespace characters with a single whitespace character. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space.

Comment: what about response.xpath('//*[@id="example"]/textarea/text()').extract()[0].strip() this works fine

Comment: Mine is a pure xpath solution. If you are happy with your solution, you might want to post this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: yup,but your tip also work fine,you got a vote,thanks